# Resamping pandas index with datetime.time type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data set that has a date-agnostic datetime.time (hour:minute) index like this:

| Time | 11/22/16 | 11/23/16 | 11/24/16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 50.9 | 51.3 | 49 |
| 00:01 | 50.8 | 51.8 | 49.9 |
| 00:02 | 51.4 | 52.6 | 48.3 |

I'm trying to do various stats on date-agnostic time slots, e.g. (avg, stddev, etc.) for the time 00:01, so having them aligned like this helps with that, but it seems a date-agnostic index makes things much harder to work with other parts of pandas. Does anyone have recommendations for how to deal with date-agnostic indexes like this or how to do date-agnostic stats if I were to just reorganize the data set such that the three date columns are one continuous column and the index being a true datetime timestamp?

The particular problem I am facing right now is that I want to upsample the dataset with [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html?highlight=ffill#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill) such that it has 60 samples per minute (second accuracy).

So the resulting df would look something like:

| Time | 11/22/16 | 11/23/16 | 11/24/16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 50.9 | 51.3 | 49 |
| 00:00:01 | 50.9 | 51.3 | 49 |
| 00:00:02 | 50.9 | 51.3 | 49 |
| 00:00:03 | 50.9 | 51.3 | 49 |
| … | … | … | … |
| 00:01:00 | 50.8 | 51.8 | 49.9 |
| … | … | … | … |
| 00:02:00 | 51.4 | 52.6 | 48.3 |
| … | … | … | … |

What I'm having trouble with is `datetime.time` is not accepted by [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) as a `DateTime-like index'. I can add an artificial date to the initial dataset like:

| Time | 11/22/16 | 11/23/16 | 11/24/16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1899-12-30 00:00:00 | 50.9 | 51.3 | 49 |
| 1899-12-30 00:01:00 | 50.8 | 51.8 | 49.9 |
| 1899-12-30 00:02:00 | 51.4 | 52.6 | 48.3 |

but this seems a little absurd. I also came up with a way of using [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.DataFrame.explode) to do this:

```py
df['ListOfTimes'] = pd.Series(
        [np.full((1, 60), df['Time'][x]).tolist()[0] for x in range((len(df.index)))])
    df = df.explode('ListOfTimes')
```

But doing things like this are SOO much more painful than create and debug than just `df.resample('60S').ffill()`. Looking for the most panda-centric way of dealing with date-agnostic time indexes.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a generator that yields the time intervals using [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals), and then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
s = (f"{i}:{n:02}" for i in df["Time"] for n in range(0, 60))

print (df.assign(Time=df["Time"]+":00").set_index("Time").reindex(s).ffill())

          11/22/16  11/23/16  11/24/16
Time                                  
00:00:00      50.9      51.3      49.0
00:00:01      50.9      51.3      49.0
00:00:02      50.9      51.3      49.0
00:00:03      50.9      51.3      49.0
00:00:04      50.9      51.3      49.0
...            ...       ...       ...
00:02:55      51.4      52.6      48.3
00:02:56      51.4      52.6      48.3
00:02:57      51.4      52.6      48.3
00:02:58      51.4      52.6      48.3
00:02:59      51.4      52.6      48.3

[180 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Looks promising! Can you explain what the `f"{i}:{n:02}"` syntax is doing? According to my debugger s resolves as a `generator` but I haven't seen this syntax before. Could you provide a link to the documentation covering this? 

Also I'm getting the following error on the `print` line:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'str'`

Comment: That is called [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals). You can try `df["Time"] = df["Time"].astype(str)` before everything.

Comment: There is so much in this that I am unpacking and learning, so thank you for this. I'm far from a python expert, so in the interest of having others at my level understand this solution better, can you add links in your answer to the f-string you mentioned and point out that "The result is then formatted using the format() protocol. " which is why `{n:02}` will result in the `range(0,60)` generating `00, 01, 02, ..` and that the [integer presentation formatter type](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#formatspec) `'d'` is the default and thus unnecessary.

Comment: Also adding an overall summary of what `s` is in that it is a generator that will generate strings of values `00:00:00, 00:00:01, 00:00:02 ..` which is the array-like input required for `reindex` . Did I understand it all right?

Comment: Adding link to [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and referencing the Examples section showing that "Generators can be composed" in the way you did. The more I learn about your answer the more I am impressed! A memory efficient one-liner.

Comment: I would also add that instead of using `ffill()` I use `fillna(method=ffill, limit=60)` so I can maintain null/NaN values where data was missing in the original dataset. Not included in my original post as a criteria for a solution, but looks to be a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange your DataFrame into a time series, resample, and go back to your one-day-per-column format like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# One day per column.  We will upsample from four to two hours.
df = pd.DataFrame({'2020-01-01': [1,2,3,4,5,6], '2020-01-02': [7,8,9,10,11,12]}, 
                  index=['0:00', '4:00', '8:00', '12:00', '16:00', '20:00'])

# One-liner
df.stack() \
  .reset_index() \
  .apply(lambda x: (pd.Timestamp(x['level_1']+'T'+x['level_0']), x[0]), 
         axis='columns', result_type='expand') \
  .set_index(0) \
  .resample('2H').ffill() \
  .reset_index() \
  .apply(lambda x: (str(x[0].date()), str(x[0].time()), x[1]), 
         axis='columns', result_type='expand') \
  .set_index([1,0]) \
  .unstack() \
  .ffill()
```

The result is:

```
                  2           
0        2020-01-01 2020-01-02
1                             
00:00:00        1.0        7.0
02:00:00        1.0        7.0
04:00:00        2.0        8.0
06:00:00        2.0        8.0
08:00:00        3.0        9.0
10:00:00        3.0        9.0
12:00:00        4.0       10.0
14:00:00        4.0       10.0
16:00:00        5.0       11.0
18:00:00        5.0       11.0
20:00:00        6.0       12.0
22:00:00        6.0       12.0
```